# Phrase about movie stars

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a phrase about those movie stars who are just good-looking but mediocre acting and those maybe not so good-looking (compare with those good-looking ones) but amazing skilled acting movie stars? Something like, 'teenager eye candy'? Is there any specific words or phrase for these two?

Comment: Could be bit-part actor. Or someone that overacts is called a ham-actor

Answer (score 5):

The phrase "eye candy" that you used is pretty apposite for actors of this sort. Other times we just call them "Megan Fox".

Actors of the opposite sort are usually just called "good actors".

Comment: Megan FOX????? Come on, we ain't judging here, we're dicussing here, haha! Although I really agree with you on this one, still, no other words or phrase at all??? And "good actors", that's just not strong enough for what I wanna express:)

Comment: @Daisy Then use 'great actors'. Or 'excellent actors'. Or 'amazing actors'. Or ...

Comment: +1 for eye candy.  The opposite sort you might describe as "exceptionally talented thespians."

Answer (score 1):

1) "Not just a pretty face" is a common antonym, so "just a pretty face" would be understood.

2) It's not quite right, but [character actor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_actor) is close.  Many people in this category would also be described as character actors.

Comment: Character actor often implies especially ugly

Answer (score 1):

There's also the old-fashioned "matinee idol," which means a male actor known primarily for his looks.